# How to add vertical label on the right side of ggplot graph?

Tags: r, ggplot2

If you look at my image, i want to add some text vertically to label my "-1 to 1" facet grids in between the legend and the graph. What would i use to do this? Annotate seems to be giving me some trouble.

[image]

Comment: Please, post your code.

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're trying to do. Can you make a mockup of what you want to see (for example by putting your desired annotations on the picture in Paint) so we can understand better? And, as Christian said, please include your code and a [mcve] of your data using the `dput` function so we can reproduce your plot.

Answer (score 2):

You can add the annotation with `labs(tag=...)` and position it (and the legend) with `theme` elements. Here is an example:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(grid)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(disp, mpg, color=factor(am))) + geom_point() +
  facet_grid(vs ~ cyl) +
  labs(tag='My text') +
  #annotation_custom(grob=textGrob(label='My text', rot=-90)) +
  theme(legend.box.margin=margin(l=20),
        plot.tag=element_text(angle=-90),
        plot.tag.position=c(.85, 0.5))
```

[image]

Comment: How to obtain the same results if you want your labs on the right, but the legend on top? 
The labs would appear out of the figure margins